# Getting exception on adding SSL binding to IIS site through code "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I have a scenario where I need to start an IIS Site with SSL binding on a code condition. Below the code snippet

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
var webService = serverManager.Sites["webService"];
if (webService != null)
{
    serverManager.Sites.Remove(webService);
}

serverManager.Sites.Add("webService", "http", "*:8000:", phyPath);
serverManager.Sites["webService"].Bindings.Add("*:8001:", certificate.GetCertHash(), "My");
serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

It all executes well if I run it on http. But when adding SSL binding with certificate it throws this exception.

```
"A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)"
```

Reading about this error, somewhere I read that it shouldn't be present in personal store and IIS - Server certificates, so I made sure it's not present before running the code. It also didn't work.

For testing I am using a self-signed certificate which I don't think should be an issue. Also didnt find any such thing when searching about this error. This certificate is a .cer certificate.

Comment: If you just do this line `certificate.GetCertHash()` does it work?

Comment: @zaitsman - I did not get your question? Another time for a different service, when I ran this through powershell that worked with passing certificate hash. Forgot to mention this is .cer certificate - that is public certificate.

Comment: The error may happen because that the underlying COM api can't access the keys (possibly) to return the hash. Further, if the cert is not installed in the Computer Personal store WITH private keys, binding will not work.

Comment: Even with certificates in the store I got the same error. Another thing is this executes as as service with NT AUTHORITY as user on Windows. Where as w3wp runs under IIS APPPOOL  . Could that be an issue to access keys?

Comment: `NT AUTHORITY` is not a user, it is a group name, inside it there are users such as `LocalSystem`, `NetworkService` among others. If you are using a `NetworkService` user and the user profile is not loaded, you may actually get that exception.